# DateField with calendar Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I want to use a kind of calendar like in the django-admin panel to select the date. I tried to use this but it doesn`t show the calendar.

```
aDate = forms.DateField(widget = AdminDateWidget)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your problem a bit more. I seem to have trouble understanding you.

Comment: the datefield works but I want to have a calendar to choose the date just like in the admin page or something like that

Answer (score 0):

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

from .models import MyModel         

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['aDate'].widget = widgets.AdminDateWidget()
```

add these css and js in your template

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'admin/css/forms.css' %} "/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'admin/css/base.css' %} "/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'admin/css/global.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="{% static 'admin/css/widgets.css' %}"/>


<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="{% static 'admin/js/core.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="{% static 'admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="{% static 'admin/js/jquery.init.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="{% static 'admin/js/actions.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="{% static 'admin/js/calendar.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="{% static 'admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js' %}"></script>
```